Dis/Proving that there is a real $x$ that satisfies $x^2 + x + 1 < 0$
I am currently practising my proof writing on some real analysis problems. Here is a problem I've been working on:

Prove or Disprove: $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 + x + 1 < 0$

There is a nice way to show this using the fact that the LHS, as a function, has no real roots, hence the inequality is false. But I wanted to try prove this using inequalities and just wanted to check if my reasoning is correct or could be improved. My proof goes something like this:
Suppose $\exists x \in \mathbb{R} \;\;such\;that\;\; x^2 + x + 1 < 0$.

If $x>0$, then $x^2 > 0$. Since we know $1 > 0 \implies x^2 + x + 1 > 0$. Therefore $x \ngtr 0$

If $x = 0$, then $x^2 = 0$. Since we know $1 > 0 \implies x^2 + x + 1 = 1 > 0$. Therefore $x \neq 0$

If $x < 0$, then we have two possible cases.
a. If $-1<x<0 \implies 0<x+1<1 \implies 0>x(x+1)>x \implies x(x+1) > -1 \implies x(x+1)+1>0$ which is a contradiction
b. If $x<-1 \implies x+1<0 \implies x(x+1)>0 \implies x(x+1)+1 > 1$ which is also a contradiction


Therefore, our initial assumption must be false, and $\nexists x \in \mathbb{R} \;\;such\;that\;\; x^2+x+1 <0 \;\;\;\;\blacksquare$
Is this a rigorous enough proof? And are there ways to improve the proof? Thanks!

Your proof seems right, though technically you would also have to cover the $x=-1$ case.

Looks correct to me, but the presentation could use some improvement. Mainly I would suggest you use less symbols where it's not necessary and instead just use words. For example instead of writing "Suppose $\exists x\in\mathbb R$ such that $x^2+x+1<0$", I would suggest you write "Suppose there exists an $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $x^2+x+1<0$". It makes things more readable, and the same goes for what you write later.

A quicker solution to the problem is also completing the square. Indeed for any $x\in\mathbb R$ we have that
$$x^2+x+1=x^2+2\frac{1}{2}x+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+1=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\geq\frac{3}{4}>0.$$

Thanks for your help! I usually try to write less by using symbols instead of words, but it does make more sense to use words for readability.

Yes, words please. If you insist on symbols don't say "If ... $\implies$ ..." since the "if" is built in to the "$\implies$".

@thelongisland756 symbols can be good for when you need to save time by writing less, such as when lecturing on a blackboard, but when you're trying to convey something in pure text then it's usually better to keep them minimal to increase readability

Another way to prove this might be something like this:
Since $a^2\geq 0,\ \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$, it follows $\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\geq0$.
Expanding $\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$, we get $$x^2+x+\frac{1}{4}\geq 0$$
Now, if we add $\frac{3}{4}$ to both sides, we get
$$x^2+x+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\geq \frac{3}{4}>0$$
Therefore, $x^2+x+1>0$

Thanks so much for your answer! The completing the square technique works quite nicely :D

I love a proof by contradiction --- it's my go-to approach, I confess. But I've also learned that it's sometimes really not necessary. So let me walk through your proof 'fixing' it:

Prove or Disprove: $\exists x \in \mathbb{R} \;\;such\;that\;\; x^2 + x + 1 < 0$


Suppose $\exists x \in \mathbb{R} \;\;such\;that\;\; x^2 + x + 1 < 0$.

Delete that sentence, and replace it with this:
We'll show that for all $x$, we have $x^2 + x + 1 > 0$. [Notice that I'm jumping right in and declaring which side I'm on, so the reader knows what is about to be proved!] We'll divide the reals into three sets: the positives, zero, and the negatives, and prove the claim for each.


If $x>0$, then $x^2 > 0$. Since we know $1 > 0 \implies x^2 + x + 1 > 0$. Therefore $x \ngtr 0$.


Case 1: Suppose $x$ is positive; then so is $x^2$. Of course, $1$ is also positive, so the sum, $x^2 + x + 1 > 0.$


If $x = 0$, then $x^2 = 0$. Since we know $1 > 0 \implies x^2 + x + 1 = 1 > 0$. Therefore $x \neq 0$


Case 2: $x = 0$. Then $x^2 + x + 1 = 0 + 0 + 1 > 1$, as needed.


If $x < 0$, then we have two possible cases.



a. If $-1<x<0 \implies 0<x+1<1 \implies 0>x(x+1)>x \implies x(x+1) > -1 \implies x(x+1)+1>0$ which is a contradiction 



b. If $x<-1 \implies x+1<0 \implies x(x+1)>0 \implies x(x+1)+1 > 1$ which is also a contradiction


Case 3: $x < 0$. We consider separately the cases (a) $x \le -1$ and (b) $-1 < x < 0$.
In case (a), we have both $x <0$ and $x+1 \le 0$, so $x(x+1) \ge 0$. Hence
$x(x+1) +1 > 0$. But this is the same as $x^2 + x + 1 > 0$, as needed.
In case (b) we have $-1<x<0 $, so  $0<x+1<1$. Because $x$ is negative, this implies that $x\cdot 0 > x(x+1) > x \cdot 1$, i.e. $0 > x(x+1) > x$, and because $x > -1$, this gives us $x(x+1) > -1$, so $x(x+1) + 1> 0$ as needed.

Therefore, our initial assumption must be false, and $\nexists x \in \mathbb{R} \;\;such\;that\;\; x^2+x+1 <0 \;\;\;\;\blacksquare$

(Delete the sentence above)
One reflection, I might rewrite that with four cases instead of 3-with-another-split, but it still reads better (to me) than the proof by contradiction.

Thanks for the suggestions! Really appreciate the help :D

As pointed out in a comment, to be complete you must also cover the case $x=-1$.
But this tiny hole in the proof is very easy to fix.
Everything else is logically and arithmetically sound.
You might find it more convenient to prove the statement
$$(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) ( x^2 + x + 1 \geq 0 ),$$
which is equivalent to $\lnot(\exists x \in \mathbb{R} )( x^2 + x + 1 < 0)$.
Then you can consider different cases for the range of values of $x$, as you did in your proof, but you avoid all the contradictions.
Every case is just a straightforward proof.
You can easily cover $x = -1$ by combining it with either case 3(a) or 3(b).
For 3(b) this looks something like this:

If $ x\leq -1$ then $ x+1\leq 0$, so $x(x+1)\geq 0$, so $x(x+1)+1 \geq 1 > 0$.

Now here's an alternative approach to 3(a):

If $-1<x<0$ then $x^2 > 0$ and $x^2 + x + 1 > 0 + (-1) + 1 = 0$.

Notice that the train of logic never uses the assumption that $x < 0$.
So we can remove that assumption:

If $-1<x$ then $x^2 \geq 0$ and $x^2 + x + 1 > 0 + (-1) + 1 = 0$.

Now we don't need cases 1 or 2, because this covers them.

Ahh I nvever noticed that we can just cover the case $x > -1$, thanks for pointing that out !

In your proof you did use the assumption that $x < 0$. But there are often multiple ways to get the same conclusion in a step of a proof, and some may use fewer assumptions than others.

1)For $x \ge 0 :$
$x^2+x+1 >0;$
2)For $x \le - 1:$
$x^2+x \ge 0;$
3)For $x \in (-1,0):$
$x+1 >0;$
Hence?
Another option:
Note:
For $x \rightarrow \pm \infty $
$f(x):=x^2+x+1$ goes to
$+$infinity.
The discriminant of the quadratic expression, $b^2-4ac$, is negative;
It follows that $f(x)$ has no real roots.
Hence?
